# Use Mercurial in build to generate a change log between the last releases

Tags: mercurial

Currently I am trying to figure out how to automatically produce a changelog. The plan was to use the default branch and mark commits with a label as "delivered to customer" the Label should have the version number.

So I added 3 Labels (Version0,Version1,Version2) to branch "default". Now I want to generate a hg log for

> "Current Tag" of branch=default to "Current Tag -1"

But .. I cant figure out the right syntax.

I tried things similar to:

```
hg log --branch=default --rev="tag()" --template=Changelog => no Error but no result
hg log --branch=default --rev="tag(Version0):tag(Version1)" --template=Changelog => Errors Version0 does not exist.
```

Can someone give/or point me to correct syntax. I would prefer a solution where I don't need to know the tag names.

Something like: Log for branch=default where from last to last -1 where Tag exists.

Optional: I found the "tag Part" also without --rev used like "tag()::tag()" but I cant figure out which part of hg Documentation (function name) I have to look into...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll show the whole process on local clone of hg-git repo with a lot of tags as version-numbers, but you **have** to read `hg help revisions` carefully after all.

- Starting point (almost identical to your command)`hg log -r "tag() & branch(default)" --style compact` (output truncated for readability)

  253[0.1.0]   505d7cdca198   2009-09-30 14:39 -0500   kbullock
  package with distutils

  269[0.2.0]   77d6c9eb02fb   2009-12-26 12:42 -0600   durin42
  setup: bump to 0.2.0

  278[0.2.1]   21ead8190d9c   2009-12-26 13:46 -0600   durin42
  setup: bump to 0.2.1

  322[0.2.2]   a222399a59d7   2010-05-22 22:12 -0500   durin42
  Bump version 0.2.2

  348[0.2.3]   5d39b98e5083   2010-07-05 11:56 -0500   durin42
  Bump version to 0.2.3

  358[0.2.4]   b53421918a89   2010-08-25 15:45 -0500   durin42
  setup: bump version number

  ...

  1698[0.9.0]   c17c6c915646   2020-08-06 16:31 +0200   georges
  Setting version for 0.9.0

  1814[0.10.0]   d3af25aa2864   2021-01-11 15:58 +0100   danchr
  setup: bump version to 0.10.0

OK, I got

1. all (only) tagged revisions without revisions in range
2. newest revisions are on bottom

and I'll fix noted problems now

- `hg log -r "limit(reverse(tag() & branch(default)),2)" --style compact`

  1814[0.10.0]   d3af25aa2864   2021-01-11 15:58 +0100   danchr
  setup: bump version to 0.10.0

  1698[0.9.0]   c17c6c915646   2020-08-06 16:31 +0200   georges
  Setting version for 0.9.0

Not bad, but

- Now I have to reference to first and second revisions in `hg log` for range `SECOND::FIRST` and use limit() predicate twice with some magic

Last release (one first changeset in list) `hg log -r "limit(reverse(tag() & branch(default)),1)" --style compact`

```
1814[0.10.0]   d3af25aa2864   2021-01-11 15:58 +0100   danchr
  setup: bump version to 0.10.0
```

Previous release (second changeset in list - one changeset with offset 1 from list) `hg log -r "limit(reverse(tag() & branch(default)),1,1)" --style compact`

```
1698[0.9.0]   c17c6c915646   2020-08-06 16:31 +0200   georges
  Setting version for 0.9.0
```

- Revset for range, first iteration `hg log -r "limit(reverse(tag() & branch(default)),1,1)::limit(reverse(tag() & branch(default)),1)" --style compact`

  1698[0.9.0]   c17c6c915646   2020-08-06 16:31 +0200   georges
  Setting version for 0.9.0

  1699   940082ab0f8a   2020-08-06 17:08 +0200   georges
  Added tag 0.9.0 for changeset c17c6c915646

  1700   746310cba0a3   2020-08-06 17:10 +0200   georges
  Added signature for changeset c17c6c915646

  1701   8b51b82cfb48   2020-08-06 14:53 +0200   a
  tests: demostrate crash on nonempty hg incoming when gitnode() is in template

  ...

  1813   635107c4ad3a   2021-02-01 18:12 +0100   danchr
  setup: adjust homepage to heptapod

  1814[0.10.0]   d3af25aa2864   2021-01-11 15:58 +0100   danchr
  setup: bump version to 0.10.0
- Revset is good, but string is too long and not-bulletproof for typing, polish it with `revsetalias` and after adding to `.hgrc` for repo into existing or created now `[revsetalias]` section something like

  rcl = limit(reverse(tag() & branch(default)),1,1)::limit(reverse(tag() & branch(default)),1)

command `hg log -r "rcl" --style compact` will produce *the same result* as previous long version, but it's at least more compact and memorable

HTH

Some notes:

1. You can|have to use any other style instead of used in testing `compact`
2. You can convert full `hg log ...` command into new hg-alias and use it as (f.e) `hg rcl`

Comment: Godlike, I would never have understood the range [SECOND :: FIRST]. Your explanation made me understand. Thanks